# Convert fname and lname to camel case while saving from model?

Tags: laravel, mutators

I have employees table in which i want to save the fname and lname colomns as camel case no matter the user input using the model. I am using ardent for validations is there any other way for this? I used mutators like bellow but still its saving as normal casing. What did i do wrong?

```
protected $fillable = [
        'fname','lname'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
  protected $table     = 'employees';

  protected $guarded   = array('id', 'password');
  public static $rules = array(
    'fname' => 'required',
    'lname' => 'required'
  );

/**
     * Make sure that first name is capitalized BEFORE saving it to the database
     *
     * @param $value
     * @return string
     */
    public function setFnameAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['fname'] = ucfirst($value);
    }

    /**
     * Make sure that last name is capitalized BEFORE saving it to the database
     *
     * @param $value
     * @return string
     */
    public function setLnameAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['lname'] = ucfirst($value);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

These mutators are correct, but you need to use Eloquent when you create a new table row to make these mutators work:

```
$employee = new Employee();
$employee->fname = $request->fname;
$employee->lname = $request->lname;
$employee->save();
```

Comment: Can i do it without mutators. Is there any plugin like Ardent where i just give the names and it directly saves it in camel cases?

Comment: @Sourav if you want to make it right, use mutators. You can override some model methods, but it's a bad idea.

Comment: Ok .. how do i make this a global thing so that i dont need to write it everytime in a model?

Comment: But the point is you shouldn't make it a global thing. It's related to the model, that's why it should stay in the model.

Answer (score 0):

Are u sure you want to convert to   [camel_case](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-camel-case)

```
public function setLnameAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['lname'] = camel_case($value);
}
```

Comment: Can i do it without mutators. Is there any plugin like Ardent where i just give the names and it directly saves it in camel cases?

Comment: Another way is to override model methods but it's not recommended